# Error while generating REST api using hyperledger composer-rest-server in centOS

Tags: linux, centos, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

**I'm able to deploy business network using hyperledger composer in CentOS linux server but while generating REST apis using composer-rest-server i'm getting connection error?**

```
[root@bctlpblockchain03 ~]#composer network ping -c admin@tutorial-network
The connection to the network was successfully tested: tutorial-network
        version: 0.15.2
        participant: org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin

Command succeeded

[root@bctlpblockchain03 ~]# composer-rest-server
? Enter the name of the business network card to use: admin@tutorial-network
? Specify if you want namespaces in the generated REST API: never use namespaces


? Specify if you want to enable authentication for the REST API using Passport:
No
? Specify if you want to enable event publication over WebSockets: Yes
? Specify if you want to enable TLS security for the REST API: No

To restart the REST server using the same options, issue the following command:
   composer-rest-server -c admin@tutorial-network -n never -w true

Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails: Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlf                                                                                        v1" for connection type "hlfv1". Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8                                                                                        .9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_                                                                                        binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/version                                                                                        s/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/e                                                                                        xtension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nv                                                                                        m/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/s                                                                                        rc/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '                                                                                        /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modul                                                                                        es/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find                                                                                         module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/n                                                                                        ode_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Ca                                                                                        nnot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest                                                                                        -server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node                                                                                        .node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/comp                                                                                        oser-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/                                                                                        grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_mod                                                                                        ules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-l                                                                                        inux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib                                                                                        /node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/n                                                                                        ode-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v                                                                                        8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension                                                                                        _binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versio                                                                                        ns/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/                                                                                        extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.n                                                                                        vm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/                                                                                        src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module                                                                                         '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modu                                                                                        les/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot fin                                                                                        d module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/                                                                                        node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for                                                                                         connection type "hlfv1". Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/li                                                                                        b/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/                                                                                        node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/                                                                                        v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extensio                                                                                        n_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versi                                                                                        ons/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node                                                                                        /extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.                                                                                        nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc                                                                                        /src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module                                                                                         '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_mod                                                                                        ules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot fi                                                                                        nd module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server                                                                                        /node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-                                                                                        Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-re                                                                                        st-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_no                                                                                        de.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/co                                                                                        mposer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x6                                                                                        4/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_m                                                                                        odules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57                                                                                        -linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/l                                                                                        ib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary                                                                                        /node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node                                                                                        /v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extensi                                                                                        on_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/vers                                                                                        ions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/nod                                                                                        e/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/                                                                                        .nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grp                                                                                        c/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find modul                                                                                        e '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_mo                                                                                        dules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'
Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection                                                                                         type "hlfv1". Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modu                                                                                        les/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-li                                                                                        nux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/                                                                                        node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/no                                                                                        de-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8                                                                                        .9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_                                                                                        binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/version                                                                                        s/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/e                                                                                        xtension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nv                                                                                        m/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/s                                                                                        rc/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '                                                                                        /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modul                                                                                        es/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find                                                                                         module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/n                                                                                        ode_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Ca                                                                                        nnot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest                                                                                        -server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node                                                                                        .node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/comp                                                                                        oser-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/                                                                                        grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_mod                                                                                        ules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-l                                                                                        inux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib                                                                                        /node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/n                                                                                        ode-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v                                                                                        8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension                                                                                        _binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versio                                                                                        ns/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/                                                                                        extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'-Cannot find module '/root/.n                                                                                        vm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/                                                                                        src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'
    at Promise.resolve.then (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/co                                                                                        mposer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/connectionprofilemanager.js:                                                                                        136:42)
    at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to rebuild it

go to the folder first

```
cd '/root/.nvm/versi ons/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/'
```

(into the folder where you have 'composer-rest-server')

then

```
npm rebuild --unsafe-prem
```

It will work now

Answer (score 1):

All the above solution works fine, but they are temporary fixed. I had the same problem and I used the `sudo npm rebuild --unsafe-prem` solution. The problem did go away for a while, but I kept running into it again and again.

I read the documentation again @ https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.

**If installing Hyperledger Composer using Linux, be aware of the following advice:

> Login as a normal user, rather than root.
>
> Do not su to root.
>
> When installing prerequisites, use curl, then unzip using sudo.
>
> Run prereqs-ubuntu.sh as a normal user. It may prompt for root
>   password as some of it's actions are required to be run as root.
>
> Do not use npm with sudo or su to root to use it.
>
> Avoid installing node globally as root.**

Doing this will really help you in long run, Goodluck !

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was "node-v57-linux-x64" I had "node-v59-linux-x64" and I solved it in the following way:

```
cd /usr/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/
```

then

```
npm rebuild --unsafe-prem
```

It worked for me the two times I had the error

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the command:

`npm rebuild --unsafe-prem`

It threw me an error saying `Warning "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir`.

I just added `sudo` and it worked well for me!:

`sudo npm rebuild --unsafe-prem`