# Not able to run composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

While starting composer rest server I am getting error :

```
Connection fails: Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection type "hlfv1". Cannot find module '/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64/grpc_node.node
```

there is no grpc_node.node file present in the above folder. I tried reinstalling compoer rest server but no luck.

Comment: Did you get any errors when you ran npm install -g composer-rest-server ? what version of linux ? how much memory do you have ?

Comment: deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported.
deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
user@1.0.0 No description
WARN user@1.0.0 No repository field.
+ composer-rest-server@0.16.2

Comment: btw I am installing it locally by npm install composer-rest-server. Node:   v8.9.3, npm: 5.6.0

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of reasons for this. the grpc module is a binary module and usually npm will download a prebuilt binary for your platform. If however it cannot do that (eg server down, or the platform is not recognised) then it will attempt to build the binary from source. 
You need to look at the output during the npm -g install of composer-rest-server to see what is reported when npm attempts to install grpc to determine what the problem is.

Comment: I guess it was because I had some other node version installed previously which was not supported by rest server. I cleaned everything up and installed again, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The following advice from another thread has worked for me. Please try:

1. Rebuild it
2. Go to the folder `cd '/root/.nvm/versi ons/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/'`
   (into the folder where you have 'composer-rest-server')
3. then run `npm rebuild --unsafe-prem`

It will work now

source - [Error while generating REST api using hyperledger composer-rest-server in centOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47759395/error-while-generating-rest-api-using-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-in-centos)